# Sphinx preamble fails to load into latex

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

When I attempt to load the cancel package with the following line in my conf.py:

```
latex_elements = {
'preamble':
    "\\usepackage{cancel}"
    }
```

The LaTeX builds fine, but the preamble never gets inserted into the tex file. I have also tried:

```
latex_elements = {
'preamble':
    r'''
    \usepackage{cancel}
    '''
    }
```

I use pdflatex engine and I have Sphinx 1.7.5.

My understanding is that anything in "preamble" should be pushed to the tex file. Is this correct?

@StevePiercy Thanks for the response. Here is my [conf](https://github.com/AguaClara/Textbook/blob/patch/conf.py#L42). I have Travis run the make Latex command, which generates [this tex.](https://github.com/AguaClara/Textbook/blob/test/latex/AguaClaraTextbook.tex) You can see all the build output on [Travis here.](https://travis-ci.org/AguaClara/Textbook/?branch=patch). You could alternatively build it locally. As you can see, the preamble is not loaded into the tex...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The syntax looks correct. Using [Pyramid docs](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L217-L327) as an example, although we use a variable instead of a string to store the preamble value, I see in our pyramid.tex file the preamble inserted starting on line 55. Try searching your .tex file.

Comment: @StevePiercy I added some more info to my question, pointing to all the different aspects of my build system. I'd love to hear any thoughts you have!

Comment: You have two `latex_elements` settings, where the second is an empty dict and overrides the first.

Comment: That's very embarrassing. Thanks so much!